# Run git status on windows terminal wsl ubuntu command line

Tags: bash, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

So i've got windows terminal and have setup my command prompt, and now I'm doing my WSL ubuntu terminals (two split horizontally in middle).

The left one is fine, the right one works but cannot run the git status command in the commandLine property at the end of the line? I want it to run after starting WSL and going to the correct directory I need (which it does). Git status just doesn't work. I have git installed FYI.

My option for the profile in `settings.json` of windows terminal (anything in caps is just placeholder as I don't want to reveal info:

```
{
  "commandline": "wsl.exe --cd \"\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\USER\\FOLDER\\FOLDER2\" git status",
  "guid": "{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f519}",
  "name": "work--git",
   ....
}
```

So then I have startup action of:

```
  "startupActions": "nt -p \"work--server\"; sp -p \"work--git\"; nt -p \"personalHub--server\"; sp -p \"personalHub--git\"; nt -p \"general\"; sp -D; ft -t 0",
```

Which opens the correct terminals and splits appropriately. Both of my WSL ones work, second one working ONLY if I remove git status (but I want that).

I've tried a lot of stuff, can anyone help who has some understanding of what could fix this?

Comment: *"Git status just doesn't work."* Apologies if I'm missing it, but I don't see anywhere in your question where you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is there an error?

Comment: Sorry, it just closes the pane as if nothing happened. Doing variations of that commandLine command, by putting things like --exec or -- before git status, it gives me either that same thing (closing of the pane never to be seen again), or process exited with code -1

Comment: Sounds kinda like the pane is just exiting as soon as `git status` is finished. That's like if you were at the prompt and typed `exit` - the shell process would exit, and the Terminal would close the tab automatically. I'd take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123192